# SocialEngine 4 - get Action name

Tags: socialengine

Looking for someone to let me know how grab the action name from a Module Core Controller and instead of executing an action use the action name as a variable for determine which content to output.

Basically, I am switching over to **SocialEngine** instead of my wordpress install and in order to keep my old page structure I am setting up modules for pulling page output. So, I setup a Controller for sculptures and then each sculpture data is stored in a database table.

So when someone goes to **MyDomain/sculptures** they would get a list pulled from the database that would dynamically generate the urls for navigating to the individual sculpture page... which would, of course, be **MyDomain/scultures/sculpturename**

Which would normally execute the **public function sculpturenameAction()** function in the controller, however, I would like to intercept the action name and execute a different function that would provide the data for the individual sculpture page based upon the action name.

Is this possible? How would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can get the current module, controller and action name using below code:

$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$module = $front->getRequest()->getModuleName();
$controller = $front->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$action = $front->getRequest()->getActionName();

If you want to divert the route or want to run some other code at some action than you can use the routeShutdown() method. Please see the below example for this:

    class yourModuleName_Plugin_Core extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

        public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

            $module = $request->getModuleName();
            $controller = $request->getControllerName();
            $action = $request->getActionName();

            //ADD YOUR ACTION CONDITION
            if ($module == 'core' && $controller == 'index' && $action == 'index') {

                //SET SOME OTHER ACTIONS OR YOU CAN WRITE SOME OTHER CODE
                $request->setModuleName('yourModuleName');
                $request->setControllerName('yourControllerName');
                $request->setActionName('yourActionName');
            }
        }
    }

Hope this answer will helps you. Thank you !!
```

Comment: Thank you @ Jitendra Bansal this reads as if it is what I am looking for but the class declaration is not exactly what I was doing. I was not creating a plugin... here is what I was using:
`class Core_SculpturesController extends Core_Controller_Action_Standard {`

Comment: Yes, Ryan you can find out action name using below code in your controller class:
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$action = $front->getRequest()->getActionName();

But if you want to divert the route to other action than you must to use routeShutdown() method.

Please let me know if have any query.